# Conditional yield in Jade

Tags: pug

In a Jade template, I want to yield in case there is something to be yielded. However, I have no idea what the condition should be.

Consider the following example:

**container.jade**

```
div
    if block
        yield
    else
        include default.jade
```

**default.jade**

```
p Nothing to show!
```

**page.jade**

```
h1 Here's a thing.
include container.jade
    p I'm a thing!
```

**empty.jade**

```
h1 Here isn't a thing.
include container.jade
```

On `page.jade`, the paragraph indented into the include would be yielded into the `container.jade`. On `empty.jade`, since there's nothing indented into the include, the contents of `default.jade` would be used in `container.jade` instead.

However, using `yield` doesn't seem to offer a `block`, thus the `if` condition is always false.

This example is severely simplified, and I'm sure that I can't do it any other way (e.g. using `extends` isn't a possibility).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this on container.jade ?

```
div
    if block
        block
    else
        include default.jade
```

Comment: I did. Nested content from an include doesn't produce a `block`, so the `if` statement is false, and even without the `if` statement, the block doesn't print anything. `yield` is the proper keyword to state where the nested content should go, but unfortunately `if yield` does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it inside a mixin:

**container.jade**

```
mixin conditionalBlock()
    if block
        yield
    else
        include default.jade
```

**page.jade**

```
include container.jade

//- Some content

h1 Here's a thing.
+conditionalBlock()
    p I'm a thing!
```

**empty.jade**

```
include container.jade

//- Some content

h1 Here isn't a thing.
+conditionalBlock()
```